# How to send the div width from an iframe to the parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, width

I want to share the div width from an iframe to the parent page.

in parent Im using:

```
var mysize = function(size) {
    console.log(size);
}
```

In the iframe, I have this:

```
<div id="loadzone" style="display: inline-block;">
content
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    parent.mysize($('#loadzone').width());
});
```

The problem is that, I'm receiving the size of the iframe width and not real div width from the iframe.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Send the first (0th) element from jQuery selector:

```
parent.mysize($('#loadzone')[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how can I get the width value?

Comment: Ah, I may have misunderstood your question. The width that is passed is likely correct. What is likely happening is that `#loadzone` element is probably the same size as your iframe. You can check this out for sure by right clicking on the element and clicking "inspect element"... in most modern browsers.

Comment: The size of the div is bigger than the iframe size. I want to pass the real div width, and seems that is taking the max size of the iframe.